# How to calculate hour:minutes from total minutes?

Tags: php, hour

For example i have 525 minutes, if we will divide it by 60 the result will be 8.75

But 1 hour have only 60 minutes not 75

How can i calculate the exact hour:minutes from total minutes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$hours = intval($totalMinutes/60);
$minutes = $totalMinutes - ($hours * 60);
```

Edited to be PHP

Comment: @Jon I would expect most programmers to be able to take this and be able to do what they want to do with it in whatever language they're working in. You're right that it's not PHP, but the question is does it give the OP the information he would need to solve the problem? I think it would.

Answer (score 9):

This kind of conversion is done using integer division and the modulo operator. With integer division you find out how many of the "large" unit you have and with modulo you find out how many of the "small" unit are left over:

```
define('MINUTES_PER_HOUR', 60);

$total_minutes = 525;
$hours = intval($total_minutes / MINUTES_PER_HOUR);  // integer division
$mins = $total_minutes % MINUTES_PER_HOUR;           // modulo

printf("%d minutes is really %02d:%02d.\n", $total_minutes, $hours, $mins);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/wvUjz)**.

Comment: Just to add to this answer. The % is the modulo operator which gives the remainder of the division. I.e. 8%5=3.

Comment: Wow great answer, thank you and thanks to other people with the answers!

Answer (score 3):

`floor(525 / 60)` gives the number of hours (`8.75` rounded down to `8`).

`525 % 60` gives the number of minutes (modulo operator).

Comment: 525 / 60 will return 8.75 but what about 75 ? have still one hour..!! how we can add this in hours?

Answer (score 1):

What I did for my girl friend made her chart with 60 min intervals  eg 1=60,2=120,3=180,4=240,5=300,6=360 etc etc. then I told her to get her minutes eg 337 find the closest number without going over that would be 5 then use the number 5 equals and subtract it from your original minutes 337-300=37 the remainder is the minutes thus 337 minutes equals 5 hours and 37 minutes