# Convert minutes into Hours and Minutes

Tags: php, date, datetime

How do I convert minutes into Hours and Minutes? E.g.

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$currDate = date_format($dt, 'Y-m-d');

$startMinutes = 939;

$startT = $currDate . " " . gmdate("H:i", $startMinutes);
```

This code returns something like '2012-09-12 00:15' instead of 15:... Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate hour:minutes from total minutes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931935/how-to-calculate-hourminutes-from-total-minutes)

Comment: Yeah that is what he wants all he forgot to do was multiply minutes by 60. You can see my answer below.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to convert `939` into?

Comment: This question proves the asker didn't even read nor understand the functions he's using.  The value of 939 would mean 939 seconds from the Julian date of 1970 or whenever timestamp started on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both the date and gmdate function get seconds as input not minutes. So all you have to do is multiply your startminutes by 60 to get your answer to work.

```
$startT = $currDate . " " . gmdate("H:i", ($startMinutes * 60));
```

Comment: The don't just take seconds, they take the number of seconds since Jan. 1, 1970 (the epoch).  So, this works because you're sending it a timestamp of `56340`, which is `January 1 1970 15:39 GMT`.

Comment: @Rocket correct I agree but based off of what he said he was looking for 15:.. if you use my answer the response you will get from gmdate("H:i",(939 * 60)); is 15:39, so I that is why I assumed this is what he was looking for.

Comment: Yeah, it outputs `15:39`, but I assumed the OP wanted to convert `939 minutes` to `15 hours`  and `39 minutes`.

Comment: I don't believe that to be true. He is creating a string with a date and time.

Comment: I wasn't sure what the OP wanted, I guess.

Comment: Yeah my guess is he is going to store it as a datetime in MySQL or something. If he needed the number of hours and minutes for a calculation then I would agree your answer works correctly. But based of him setting a variable equal to a concatenated string of date and time I guessed this is what he wanted.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't one of the answers (which was deleted because I thought that it wasn't what the OP wanted, and so the person deleted it) be better?  The deleted answer was: `$dt->modify('+939 minutes'); $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i');`.

Comment: Since he already has $dt declared then yes it probably would be a better answer assuming $start_minutes will never be more than 1440 otherwise it would switch to the next day. Hard to tell without knowing all the code around it and where the inputs are coming from.

Answer (score 7):

Something like the following formula should work:

```
$hours  = floor($minutes/60); //round down to nearest minute. 
$minutes = $minutes % 60;
```

Comment: Fast and solid solution, also takes hours > 24 into account. Good!

Comment: This answer is too good for only a single, sterile upvote. So I'm breaking the rules to say: Thank you for being alive to post such sheer elegance.

Answer (score 2):

very quick way of doing it, this should work:

```
echo date('H:i', strtotime($startMinutes.' minutes'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$dt = new DateTime('now');
$dt->modify('+939 minutes');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$d = floor ($startMinutes / 1440);
$h = floor (($startMinutes - $d * 1440) / 60);
$m = $startMinutes - ($d * 1440) - ($h * 60);

echo "{$startMinutes}min converts to {$d}d {$h}h {$m}m";
```

You should be able to piece it together from there..

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
function hour_min($minutes){
       if($minutes == 0){return '';}else{
        $hours  = round(intval($minutes/60) , 2); //round down to nearest minute.
        $minutes = $minutes % 60; return sprintf("%02d", $hours).':'.sprintf("%02d", $minutes);
       }
 }
 echo hour_min(720);  // 12:00 
 echo hour_min(480); //  08:00
```