# calculate total Hours and minutes in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I m Working on Project management system in Codeigniter

i want to calculate total hours for particular task,
for example today i worked 1 hour 20 minutes on Task A and next day i work on Task A 2 hours 30 minutes.
so my total Working hours for Task a Should be 3 hours 50 min.

How to calculate total hours like this??

i tried following thing.

```
 <?php
if (!empty($result)) {
    $i = 1;
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($result as $milestone_row) {
        ?>
        <tr id="<?php echo $milestone_row->id; ?>"> 
            <?php
            if ($is_master_admin) {
                if ($i > 1) {
                    if ($milestone_row->userid == $userid) {

                    } else {
                        $userid = $milestone_row->userid;
                        echo $milestone_row->usertitle;
                    }
                } else {
                    $userid = $milestone_row->userid;
                    echo $milestone_row->usertitle;
                }
            }
            ?>

        <li class="in">
            <a href="">Add Bug</a>
            <div class="message">
                <span class="arrow"></span>
                <span class="body">
            <?php echo $milestone_row->description; ?><br/>
            <?php echo $milestone_row->esthours; ?> hrs<br/>

                    <span class="datetime">at <?php echo $milestone_row->createddate; ?></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
                    <?php
                    $i++;

                    $total = $total + $milestone_row->esthours;

                }
            }
            ?>

<label>Total :-<input type="text" value="<?php echo $total;?>"></input>
```

Comment: you can easily do it with query but where is the structure?

Comment: Thank you @raheelshan for reply..
i got solution from following link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931935/how-to-calculate-hourminutes-from-total-minutes

Answer (score 0):

define $estHours = 0; before the loop, next you should use $estHours += $milestone_row->esthours; in the loop,

Finally in the HTML

```
 <?php echo $estHours ?> hrs<br/>
```